# How to determine if object is a valid key-value pair in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, key, key-value

1. If I have a rdd, how do I understand the data is in key:value
   format? is there a way to find the same - something like
   type(object) tells me an object's type. I tried `print
   type(rdd.take(1))`, but it just says `<type 'list'>`.
2. Let's say I have a data like `(x,1),(x,2),(y,1),(y,3)` and I use
   `groupByKey` and got `(x,(1,2)),(y,(1,3))`. Is there a way to define
   `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` as values where x and y are keys? Or does a key has to be a single value? I noted that if I use `reduceByKey` and `sum` function to get the data `((x,3),(y,4))` then it becomes much easier to define this data as a key-value pair

Comment: 1. `rdd.first()`
2. Please clarify. `groupByKey` is usually for cases you really eventually need the entire list.

Comment: 1. wouldn't  `rdd.first()` return me just the first datapoint? I want to know whether the data is in a key-value format or not. 2.Yes, I have used `groupByKey` to get the entire data, but i want it in key-value format

Comment: You want it as a map? What about collectAsMap?
Taking the first you will get a tuple, what do you mean by key-value format? what kind of type do you expect?

Comment: i couldnt find a good simple source on collectAsMap. Please share if you have anything. Would it be possible to provide a simple example?

Comment: See collectAsMap here - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD - `rdd.collectAsMap()`

Comment: thanks. So if I run `groupByKey` on my original data and then run `collectAsMap()`, would it convert my data in dictionary format even if my second elements are lists (and not a single value)?

Comment: Just try it yourself. The output would roughly be - {"a" : [1, 2, 3], "b" : [4], ..}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is a dynamically typed language and PySpark doesn't use any special type for key, value pairs. The only requirement for an object being considered a valid data for `PairRDD` operations is that it can be unpacked as follows:

```
k, v = kv
```

Typically you would use a two element `tuple` due to its semantics (immutable object of fixed size) and similarity to Scala `Product` classes. But this is just a convention and nothing stops you from something like this:

*key_value.py*

```
class KeyValue(object):
    def __init__(self, k, v):
        self.k = k
        self.v = v
    def __iter__(self):
       for x in [self.k, self.v]:
           yield x
```

```
from key_value import KeyValue

rdd = sc.parallelize(
    [KeyValue("foo", 1), KeyValue("foo", 2), KeyValue("bar", 0)]) 

rdd.reduceByKey(add).collect()
## [('bar', 0), ('foo', 3)]
```

and make an arbitrary class behave like a *key-value*. So once again if something can be correctly unpacked as a pair of objects then it is a valid *key-value*. Implementing `__len__` and `__getitem__` magic methods should work as well. Probably the most elegant way to handle this is to use `namedtuples`.

Also `type(rdd.take(1))` returns a `list` of length `n` so its type will be always the same.

Comment: I am learning from you. But I am still confused about something. Let's say for whatever reason, I used `groupByKey`, I will get `[('bar', (0)), ('foo', (1,2))]`...now can I use something like `rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],len(x[1]))`? I know the same can be done using `countByKey`, but I want to use the 'groupByKey'

Comment: `(0)` is not a valid `tuple` literal. It is just `0`. Otherwise exactly like this.