# pyspark partitioning data using partitionby

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning, rdd

I understand that `partitionBy` function partitions my data. If I use `rdd.partitionBy(100)` it will partition my data by key into 100 parts. i.e. data associated with similar keys will be grouped together

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is it advisable to have number of partitions equal to number of
       available cores? Does that make processing more efficient?
3. what if my data is not in key,value format. Can i still use this function?
4. lets say my data is serial_number_of_student,student_name. In this
           case can i partition my data by student_name instead of the
           serial_number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Not exactly. Spark, including PySpark, [is by default using **hash partitioning**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424396/1560062). Excluding identical keys there is no practical similarity between keys assigned to a single partition.
2. There is no simple answer here. All depends on amount of data and available resources. [Too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659404/spark-iteration-time-increasing-exponentially-when-using-join/31662127#31662127) or too low number of partitions will degrade the performance.

   [Some resources](https://youtu.be/7ooZ4S7Ay6Y) claim the number of partitions should around twice as large as the number of available cores. From the other hand a single partition typically shouldn't contain more than 128MB and a single shuffle block cannot be larger than 2GB (See [SPARK-6235](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235)).

   Finally you have to correct for potential data skews. If some keys are overrepresented in your dataset it can result in suboptimal resource usage and potential failure.
3. No, or at least not directly. You can use `keyBy` method to convert RDD to required format. Moreover any Python object can be treated as a **key-value pair** as long as it implements required methods which make it behave like an `Iterable` of length equal two. See [How to determine if object is a valid key-value pair in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35703298/1560062)
4. It depends on the types. As long as key is **hashable*** then yes. Typically it means it has to be immutable structure and all values it contains have to be immutable as well. For example [a list is not a valid key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31404238/1560062) but a `tuple` of integers is.

---

To quote [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable):

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.

Answer (score -1):

I recently used partitionby. What I did was restructure my data so that all those which I want to put in same partition have the same key, which in turn is a value from the data. my data was a list of dictionary, which I converted into tupples with key from dictionary.Initially the partitionby was not keeping same keys in same partition. But then I realized the keys were strings. I cast them to int. But the problem persisted. The numbers were very large. I then mapped these numbers to small numeric values and it worked. So my take away was that the keys need to be small integers.