# How can I achieve server side filtering with the join in spark dataframe api

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

This is a part of my spark app. The first part is the part where I get all the articles within the last 1 hour and the second part of the code grabs all these articles comments. The third part adds the comments to the articles. 
The problem is that the `articles.map(lambda x:(x.id,x.id)).join(axes)` part is too slow, it takes around 1 minute. I would like to improve this to 10 seconds or even less but don't know how to? Thanks for your reply.

```
articles = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="articles", keyspace=source).load() \
                        .map(lambda x:x).filter(lambda x:x.created_at!=None).filter(lambda x:x.created_at>=datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1) and x.created_at<=datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=0)).cache()

axes = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="axes", keyspace=source).load().map(lambda x:(x.article,x))

speed_rdd = articles.map(lambda x:(x.id,x.id)).join(axes)
```

**EDIT**

This is my new code, which I changed according to your suggestions. It is now already 2 times as fast as before, so thanks for that ;). Just another improvement I would like to make with the last part of my code in the axes part, which is still too slow and needs 38 seconds for 30 million data:

```
range_expr = col("created_at").between(
                            datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=timespan),
                            datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=time_delta(timespan))
                        )
        article_ids = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="article_by_created_at", keyspace=source).load().where(range_expr).select('article','created_at').persist()


        axes = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="axes", keyspace=source).load()
```

I tried this here (which should substitute the last axes part of my code) and this is also the solution I would like to have but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
in_expr = col("article").isin(article_ids.collect())
        axes = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="axes", keyspace=source).load().where(in_expr)
```

I always get this error message:

```
in_expr = col("article").isin(article_ids.collect())
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37507116/1560062) if you want to achieve reasonable performance don't convert your data to `RDD`. It not not only makes optimizations like predicate pushdown impossible, but also introduces as huge overhead of moving data out of JVM to Python.

Instead you should use use SQL expressions / `DataFrame` API in a way similar to this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, current_timestamp

range_expr = col("created_at").between(
    current_timestamp() - expr("INTERVAL 1 HOUR"),
    current_timestamp())

articles = (sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(...).load()
    .where(col("created_at").isNotNull())  # This is not really required
    .where(range_expr))
```

It should be also possible to formulate predicate expression using standard Python utilities as you've done before:

```py
import datetime

range_expr = col("created_at").between(
    datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    datetime.datetime.now()
)
```

Subsequent `join` should be performed without moving data out of data frame as well:

```py
axes = (sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(...)
    .load())

articles.join(axes, ["id"])
```

Comment: a) `isin` has been introduced in 1.5 b) I am pretty sure what you want is to flatten this `article_ids.collect()` first.

Comment: I tried to flatten it but it didn't really increase speed. When loading, this part sqlContext.read.format has a default partition number of 255 and I would like to make it smaller, since this part reads from cassandra according to partitions is slow, but don't know how to. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1) Predicate Pushdown is automatically detected by the Spark-Cassandra connector, as long as the filtering is possible in Cassandra (using primary key for filtering or secondary index): https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#pushing-down-clauses-to-cassandra

2) For more efficient joins, you can call the method `repartitionByCassandraReplica`. Unfortunately this method may not be available for PySpark, only for Scala/Java API. Read the doc here: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12

3) Another hint is to try to debug and understand how the connector is creating Spark partitions. There are some examples and caveats mentioned in the docs: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/16_partitioning.md