# Python spark Dataframe to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I can't figure out how to write a dataframe to elasticsearch using python from spark. I followed the steps from [here](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/prasanth-kothuri/2016-05-integrating-hadoop-and-elasticsearch-%E2%80%93-part-2-%E2%80%93-writing-and-querying).

Here is my code:

```
# Read file
df = sqlContext.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
    .options(header='true') \
    .load('/vagrant/data/input/input.csv', schema = customSchema)

df.registerTempTable("data")

# KPIs
kpi1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM data")

es_conf = {"es.nodes" : "10.10.10.10","es.port" : "9200","es.resource" : "kpi"}
kpi1.rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-',
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf=es_conf)
```

Above code gives

> Caused by: net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero
>   arguments for construction of ClassDict (for
>   pyspark.sql.types._create_row)

I also started the script from:
 `spark-submit --master spark://aggregator:7077 --jars ../jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.4.0/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.4.0.jar /vagrant/scripts/aggregation.py` to ensure that `elasticsearch-hadoop` is loaded

Comment: which version of elasticseach are you using ?

Comment: @eliasah`2.4.0`, tried also using `elasticsearch-hadoop-5.0.0-alpha5.jar` for the 2.x versions of es

Answer (score 4):

For starters `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` expects a `RDD` of `(key, value)` pairs and in your case [this may happen only accidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35703298/1560062). The same thing applies to the value format you declare.

I am not familiar with Elastic but just based on the arguments you should probably try something similar to this:

```
kpi1.rdd.map(lambda row: (None, row.asDict()).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(...)
```

Since Elastic-Hadoop provide SQL Data Source you should be also able to skip that and save data directly:

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").save(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

As zero323 said, the easiest way to load a Dataframe from PySpark to Elasticsearch is with the method

```
Dataframe.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").save("index/type")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.resource", '%s/%s' % (conf['index'], conf['doc_type'])).option("es.nodes", conf['host']).option("es.port", conf['port']).save()
```