# How To Push a Spark Dataframe to Elastic Search (Pyspark)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Beginner ES Question here

**What is the workflow or steps for pushing a Spark Dataframe to Elastic Search?**

From research, I believe I need to use the [spark.newAPIHadoopFile()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/python/pyspark.html) method.

However, digging through the [Elastic Search Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html), and [other Stack Q/A's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559121/python-spark-dataframe-to-elasticsearch) I am still a little confused on what format the arguments need to be in and why

NOTE that I am using pyspark, this is a new table to ES (no index already exists), and the df is 5 columns (2 string types, 2 long types,  and 1 list of ints) with ~3.5M rows.

Comment: Here is a compilation of few working code snippets which index data into Elasticsearch - https://medium.com/@akkidx/indexing-into-elasticsearch-using-spark-code-snippets-55eabc753272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to find an answer so I'll share. Spark DF's (from pyspark.sql) don't currently support the `newAPIHadoopFile()` methods; however, `df.rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile()` was giving me errors as well. The trick was to convert the df to strings via the following function

```
def transform(doc):
    import json
    import hashlib

    _json = json.dumps(doc)
    keys = doc.keys()
    for key in keys:
        if doc[key] == 'null' or doc[key] == 'None':
            del doc[key]
    if not doc.has_key('id'):
        id = hashlib.sha224(_json).hexdigest()
        doc['id'] = id
    else:
        id = doc['id']
    _json = json.dumps(doc)
    return (id, _json)
```

So my JSON workflow is:

1: `df = spark.read.json('XXX.json')`

2: `rdd_mapped = df.rdd.map(lambda y: y.asDict())`

3: `final_rdd = rdd_mapped.map(transform)`

4:

```
final_rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
     path='-', 
     outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
     keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",  
     valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
     conf={ "es.resource" : "<INDEX> / <INDEX>", "es.mapping.id":"id", 
         "es.input.json": "true", "es.net.http.auth.user":"elastic",
         "es.write.operation":"index", "es.nodes.wan.only":"false",
         "es.net.http.auth.pass":"changeme", "es.nodes":"<NODE1>, <NODE2>, <NODE3>...",
         "es.port":"9200" })
```

More [information on ES arguments can be found here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html) (Scroll to 'Configuration')

Comment: the important thing here for me was `"es.mapping.id":"id"` - thanks! (this allows you to set your own id)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me - I had my data in `df`.

```
df = df.drop('_id')
df.write.format(
    "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql"
).option(
    "es.resource", '%s/%s' % (conf['index'], conf['doc_type'])
).option(
    "es.nodes", conf['host']
).option(
    "es.port", conf['port']
).save()
```

I had used this command to submit my job - `/path/to/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --jars ./jar_files/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.4.jar --driver-class-path ./jar_files/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.4.jar main_df.py`.