# pySpark - groupByKey Not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the bellow data- I want to group with the first element - I am trying with pySpark core ( NOT Spark SQL)

```
(u'CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT', u'HZ256372', u'003', u'43'), 
(u'THEFT', u'HZ257172', u'011', u'27'), 
(u'ASSAULT', u'HY266148', u'019', u'6'), 
(u'WEAPONS VIOLATION', u'HY299741', u'010', u'29'), 
(u'CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT', u'HY469211', u'025', u'19'), 
(u'NARCOTICS', u'HY313819', u'016', u'11'), 
(u'NARCOTICS', u'HY215976', u'003', u'42'), 
(u'NARCOTICS', u'HY360910', u'011', u'27'), 
(u'NARCOTICS', u'HY381916', u'015', u'25')
```

I tried with

```
file.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
```

this didnt worked out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't work. `groupByKey` can be called only on RDD of key-value pairs ([How to determine if object is a valid key-value pair in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35703298)) and a tuple of arbitrary length is not.

Decide which value is a key and `map` or `keyBy` first. For example

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1:])).groupByKey()
```

Comment: Adding to the above , I have to play with list()  else we will get an error like "pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable"  Thanks for the response -

Answer (score 0):

**Got this worked with the bellow code**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
def chicagofile(line):
        sLine = line.split(",")
        cNum = sLine[1]
        cDist = sLine[11]
        cType = sLine[5]
        cCommArea = sLine[13]
        return (cType,cNum,cDist,cCommArea)
cFile = sc.textFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/ChicagoCrime15/crimes2015.csv")
getFile = cFile.map(chicagofile)
mapCType = getFile.map(lambda x : (x[0],(x[1],x[2],x[3])))
grp = mapCType.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], (list(x[1]))))
saveFile = grp.saveAsTextFile("/user/sachinkerala6174/inData/ChicagoCrime15/res1")
print grp.collect()
```