# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str using pyspark and RDD

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm new to Python. I'm also new to pysaprk. I'm trying to run a code line that takes (kv[0], kv[1]) and then run an ngrams() function on kv[1].

Also here is the sample layout of the `mentions` data that the code works on:

```
Out[12]: 
[{'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamchatka_Peninsula',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warthead_sculpin',
  'span': (100, 119),
  'text': u' It is native to the northern.'},
 {'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warthead_sculpin',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warthead_sculpin',
  'span': (4, 20),
  'text': u'The warthead sculpin ("Myoxocephalus niger").'}]
```

This is the code that I'm working with:

```
    def build(self, mentions, idfs):
            m = mentions\
                .map(lambda (source, target, span, text): (target, text))
                .flatMapValues(lambda v: ngrams(v, self.max_ngram))
                .map(lambda v: (v, 1))
                .reduceByKey(add)\
```

How should the data from the previous step be formulated to resolve this error??
Any help or guidance will be truly appreciated.

I'm using python 2.7 and pyspark 2.3.0.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapValues` can be applied only on a RDD of `(key, value)` pairs (`RDD` where each element is a `tuple` of `length` equal to 2, or some object that behaves as one - [How to determine if object is a valid key-value pair in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35703298/9613318))

You data is a dictionary, so it doesn't qualify. It is not clear what you expect there, but you suspect you want:

```
from operator import itemgetter

(mentions
  .map(itemgetter("_id", "text"))
  .flatMapValues(lambda v: ngrams(v, self.max_ngram))
  .map(lambda v: (v, 1)))
```

Comment: May I ask why you suggested the usage of flatMapValues then mapValue? I added the rest of the method for a clearer vision (it counts tfidf). Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did what you suggested and it caused a type error. I edit the question to show the triggered error.